# Facebook Android SSO weird Error

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I made a previous post and I fixed the issue in that problem but I get something weirder now. So I'm following http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/Android/build/#register and everything goes fine until I actually start my app. Instead of getting an app log in page, I get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfBJT.jpg

I have no clue why it won't go to the app log-in page like it does for everyone else. The only thing that perhaps might be different is that I had to remove the "@Override" notations for the Facebook.authorize method call.

```
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Comment: You won't get the app login page if you're not logged in to facebook, what the pic you added shows is a facebook login page, which is the first step in the authentication process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this surely you will solve your error
you need to install an extension, similar to the core Android SDK, but no, here is what you need to do:

1.) go to github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

2.) download the facebook directory ONLY! The other directories are only examples.

3.) Put the files from the src (you can copy the drawables too, if you want to) in the package, you are currently working with

4.) You are good to go, you can use the facebook "SDK"

see also this example https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook download it , it is working example provided by facebook

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. So what I had to do to fix my problem was to not install the Facebook.apk that is in the github repository, which I was doing previously. Now the proper app page shows up and everything. Perhaps there is some weird simulator thing going on. It's good that this works for the time being, but I'm worried about later, because people inevitably will have the Facebook app installed on their droid machines.